# Swagger curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: text/plain' -d '{ \

Tags: curl, post, header, swagger

> [Response Body :Bad request]

Anyone could help me please why it's a bad request ? 
Swagger

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: 
text/plain' -d '{ \ 
   "email": "aaaa%40gmail.fr", \ 
   "password": "123yt", \ 
   "confirmPassword": "123yt" \ 
}' 'http://localhost:1413/Account/Register'
```

[image]